# How to refer to button outside of switch block

Tags: java, android

In my following code. I am trying to assign a different theOperator string to each button (plus, minus, subtract) and then refer to them in the Equal case using an if statement.  I tried defining theOperator in the plus case, but I just learned that different cases cannot see each other. How do I define the theOperator outside of the switch block, but still have it defined for the id Add?

```
package rechee.cool;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public EditText display;

    double counter1 = 0;
    double counter2 = 0;
    String theOperator = new String("+");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Associate the button variable with the xml reference

        display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }

    String display1 = display.getText().toString();

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bOne:
                display.append("1");
                break;
            case R.id.bTwo:
                display.append("2");
                break;
            case R.id.bThree:
                display.append("3");
                break;
            case R.id.bFour:
                display.append("4");
                break;
            case R.id.bFive:
                display.append("5");
                break;
            case R.id.bSix:
                display.append("6");
                break;
            case R.id.bSeven:
                display.append("7");
                break;
            case R.id.bEight:
                display.append("8");
                break;
            case R.id.bNine:
                display.append("9");
                break;
            case R.id.bZero:
                display.append("0");
                break;
            case R.id.bPoint:
                display.append(".");
                break;
            case R.id.bClear:
                display.setText("");
                break;
            case R.id.bAdd:
                double displayValue = Double.parseDouble(display1);
                counter1 += displayValue;
                display.setText("");
                //String theOperator= new String("+");
                break;
            case R.id.bEqual:
                //display.setText(Double.toString(counter2));
                //counter1 = 0;
                // Tried using a switch for theOperator, but 1.6 doesn't allow string switch. So I'm going to use if else statements instead.
                if (theOperator == "+") {

                }

        }
        //case "+":
        //break;

    }

}
```

Comment: In switch, when you break each case statement, only one case executes, what do you mean by use something from one in another case?

Comment: I want to be able to check that if button equal is clicked, check if another button was clicked (either plus, multiply, divide, or subtrack). I haven't added the code of the rest of those buttons, yet. And then I have seperate code for if each of those buttons were clicked.

Comment: Also, what you have done instead of the case statements and why is append useless?

Comment: No I defintely agree.. I have bit more than I can chew. I did a caculator in C#. But I followed a tutorial. This was me basically doing it from scratch. Any tutorial you recommend? I was going through new boston. And as to the appendage, I'm appending the text to the screen so the user can enter multiple numbers. Not only that, but I need the user to be able to have a number after they enter a point (.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be as easy as adding a flag that switches on if an operator is pressed.